# Is there a way to run an SWF file from another server? e.g. a file-hosting site

Tags: flash

I'm wondering if it's possible to have an SWF file be played from a file hosting site onto my own site via HTML? Like for example, if I want to run an SWF file from `examplefilehost.com/foo.swf` onto my site, how can I do that?

I have tried some of the more common sites (e.g. Google Drive and Mega) but they don't work, Ruffle doesn't render the SWF files for me.

Comment: I googled a bit and I think this might be due to Ruffle subjects to CORS (simply, it's a crossdomain security for browsers): https://github.com/ruffle-rs/ruffle/discussions/8972